# Interface Builder (XIB) or Code when merging in a team environment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, interface-builder

Merging interface builder files with others (and even myself from a different computer) can be a real challenge.  The XIB xml is certainly better than NIBs but even as xml, I've found cases where merging and getting a consistent and valid XIB was harder than just taking the other and manually redoing the changes made.

I'm wondering what other folks are doing who have multiple folks who can potentially collide on XIBs.

**Was merging a consideration for going all code?  Do you use XIBs just for layout and code the rest?  Or, have you had any luck merging XIBs and over time you just get better at manually reading?**

EDIT: My current approach is using it for strict layout (what it's really good at and painful to code) and setting all the options and data via code.  I find code much easier to merge but laying out controls in code is tedious.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was merging a consideration for going all code?

Yes, No, and "Portions Of". It depends on things like:

- The people involved
- the complexity of the UI
- the quality of the implementation you need.
- the expected lifetime of the implementation

But yes, it has been, and it often is when the case is just not trivial -- Otherwise, you just fight it by decomposing XIBs into smaller pieces. That can work pretty well (or not), depending on what you are faced with.

> Do you use XIBs just for layout and code the rest?

Depends on a lot of things.

- XIB-only has its restrictions, and is much like code duplication. I use it at times for prototyping, other times because that's what somebody else favored.
- "A little of both" can require a lot of glue. At times, it can be pretty disorganized -- e.g. "where's that action *really* set?". Of course, this can also be used to achieve what some would consider a good balance of XIB and programmatic separation. The simpler the XIB is, the less often it will need to be adjusted, and less likely it will cause merge conflicts.
- Code-only is my preference, but there are people who just prefer WYSIWYG, and people aren't very familiar writing UIs programmatically. As well, if quality, reusability, and maintainability not requirements (e.g. bang out a prototype), then code-only can be overkill.

> Or, have you had any luck merging XIBs and over time you just get better at manually reading?

No real luck -- just by breaking them into smaller components. Unfortunately, the "Decompose Interface" option (from IB3) is not available in Xc4's editor.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that IB is better for layout as you mention, but probably that's just me cause I was raised this way.Plus code is way more re-usable than layouts.

As far as I'm concerned during the runtime both act the same though I'm not 100% sure about that. Prototypes are less painful in IB than in code, I know that for sure and clients will not take any value on you prototyping in code.

Comment: agreed on code being more re-usable and also agreed on layout being better in IB.  That's my current approach (strict layout in IB and configuring the controls in code which I can save, copy paste and diff easily).  If I have to redo the layout in a bad merge case, it's quick because it's strict layout and rebind.  Waiting to hear from others ...

Comment: Taking this as the answer because it's basically the conclusion I came to and I haven't heard other proposals for easy merging.  Code is more re-usable (cut and paste) and strict layout is easiest in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is don't bother trying to merge, just accepts the branch version completely or you version. It means you have to be a bit disciplined about who get to change the interface code, and on commits and updates, in practice we haven't found it a problem but I guess it depends on your environment. 
Don't use this as an excuse to stop using interface builder, there is nothing worse than trying to dig through someone else's code to find a button so you can work out what happens when a use clicks it.
**Without Interface Builder you are not respecting the MVC separation.**

Comment: MVC doesn't dictate Interface Builder.  I've code MVC patterns in multiple languages on multiple platforms.  Some with designers, some without.  MVC dictates your view is separate from your controller.  It is possible to have a view class, a controller class and a model classes without a xib and respect MVC.  MVC goes back to Xerox Parc in 1978/1979 and I'm pretty darn sure interface builder didn't exist :)  http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html

Comment: You're right, I am just speaking more from experience with iOS app that haven't used interface builder. They tend to have all of the view building code stuck in the view controllers.